# Why can I only play offline in Minecraft?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-launcher

When I start-up my launcher it only gives me an option to play offline. When I try to connect to any servers afterwards it gives me an error saying `Bad Login` or `Could not resolve...`.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are getting `Bad Login` the Mojang servers might be down. You can always check this on https://help.mojang.com.

For the second error, check if your internet connection is actually up and running. Try to connect to a basic website (like this one).

If you think this is a bug you can also always report a bug on https://mojang.atlassian.net/browse/MC. Be sure to be very clear and specific about your issue.

Comment: Mojang's status is inaccurate. http://xpaw.ru/mcstatus/ is more accurate. Mojang says all services are green while I still can't log in. The xPaw site says two of the five services are down, among them the Login service. The inaccuracy possibly arises because the Mojang and Minecraft services are all geographically close together while xPaw looks at the services from a distance.

Comment: @MarkJeronimus The issue has only occurred to me when the services were unstable, and while they might've been online while you checked, the few seconds after when you login they aren't anymore.

Comment: It lasted 30 minutes and only at the end were the services unstable (xPaw's site also reports that).

Answer (score 3):

Of course we're all upstanding citizens that would never dream of account-sharing, but I do think it's worth mentioning that you cannot have one minecraft account logged into multiple machines at once. So if, for example, you were to log in on your PC, then wander away from the game and forget about it (I don't recommend this), then try to log in to play on another computer, it will give you a Bad Login error.

If you've verified that the Mojang servers are up, your internet connection is active, your account isn't already logged in anywhere, you're *certain* that you're entering your username and password correctly, and you've tried restarting the launcher (I don't know why this works but sometimes it does), reinstalling Minecraft may be your best option. Back up your saves.

Comment: Restarting the launcher might work because that will refresh your login token by logging in again.

Answer (score 0):

You should make sure that you have **paid** for minecraft premium, which you can buy at [Official Site](http://www.minecraft.net/) for 25$ (I believe, can't check currently). **Do** **NOT** trust a 'free minecraft premium account' website, even if it isn't virus-ridden it is dishonest or likely illegal. If this is not the problem, and you are sure that you have a premium account, we would need more information to figure out why it does not work.

Comment: Notice that this is a self-answered question. Not having a premium account is definitely not the problem that Binero is addressing. :)

Comment: Oh, wow. I didn't realize that it was self answered, and I didn't think to look and check. Sorry about that.

Comment: However, now that I think about it, I just realized that I once had a problem with getting 'bad login' errors, and I solved it by entering a single player world and then exiting, but because it would be a very odd fix for this error, I think it was only a bug, not an error, if that makes any sense at all.

Answer (score -5):

I commonly have this problem. For me it works if I reboot my internet.